# cuPrintf does nothing (program uses pinned+mapped memory, CUBLAS also)

Tags: cuda

I need to print a few values from a CUDA kernel, and have tried using cuPrintf. My compute capability is 1.1, and so I cannot use printf. The program compiles correctly and does not give any runtime error either. However, the cuPrintf lines seem to be doing nothing at all. Here are some of the things I tried:

- Compile with -arch sm_11
- Surround each kernel invocation with cudaPrintfInit and cudaPrintfEnd
- Ensure that the number of characters is small enough to work with the default buffer size
- Ensure that cudaPrintfInit and cudaPrintfDisplay return cudaSuccess

My program uses the following in addition to the regular stuff:

- CUBLAS library
- page-locked (pinned) + mapped memory

Why isn't the call to cuPrintf doing anything?

**Edit** 
Here are some relevant snippets from the code:

```
__global__ void swap_rows(float *d_A, int r1, int r2, int n)
{
  int i = r1;
  int j = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  cuPrintf("(%d,%d) ", i, j);

  if(j >= n) return;
  float tmp;
  tmp = d_A[L(i,j)];
  d_A[L(i,j)] = d_A[L(r2,j)];
  d_A[L(r2,j)] = tmp;
}

extern "C" float *someFunction(float *_A, float *_b, int n)
{
  int i, i_max, k, n2 = n*n;
  dim3 lblock_size(32,1);
  dim3 lgrid_size(n/lblock_size.x + 1, 1);
  float *d_A, *d_b, *d_x, *h_A, *h_b, *h_x, tmp, dotpdt;

  cublasStatus status;
  cudaError_t ret;

  if((ret = cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost)) != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error setting device flag: %s\n", 
            cudaGetErrorString(ret));
    return NULL;
  }

  // Allocate mem for A and copy data
  if((ret = cudaHostAlloc((void **)&h_A, n2 * sizeof(float), 
                            cudaHostAllocMapped)) != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating page-locked h_A: %s\n", 
            cudaGetErrorString(ret));
    return NULL;
  }

  if((ret = cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **)&d_A, h_A, 0)) != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error getting devptr for page-locked h_A: %s\n", 
            cudaGetErrorString(ret));
    return NULL;
  }

  if((ret = cudaMemcpy(h_A, _A, n2 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToHost)) !=
      cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error copying A into h_A: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(ret));
    return NULL;
  }

  // Some code to compute k and i_max  

  if(cudaPrintfInit() != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaPrintfInit failed\n");

  swap_rows<<<lgrid_size,lblock_size>>>(d_A, k, i_max, n);
  if((ret = cudaThreadSynchronize()) != cudaSuccess)
    fprintf(stderr, "Synchronize failed!\n", cudaGetErrorString(ret));

  if(cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true) != cudaSuccess)
    printf("cudaPrintfDisplay failed\n");
  cudaPrintfEnd();

// Some more code
}
```

I forgot to mention: these methods are compiled separately (from the main() function) as a dynamically linked module (shared object).

Comment: Probably you should post some code. What happens if you put a cudaDeviceSynchronize() call after the kernel call and do cuda error checking on it?

Comment: @RobertCrovella - I have edited the question to include some code. Since I am using an older version of the API, I have used cudaThreadSynchronize() instead of cudaDeviceSynchronize(), and it does not return any error.

Comment: Which version are you using?  What's needed is to check the kernel call for errors, using a method like the one described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) with cudaPeekAtLastError()

Comment: @RobertCrovella - I'm on version 3.2. I checked the calls to runtime API for errors using a method similar to the one described in the link you mentioned, and no error is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: I have another kernel which gave an "invalid configuration argument" error. I was using a block size of 32*32*1 for that kernel, and this exceeds the maximum number of threads permissible per block. As soon as this was fixed, the cuPrintf's started working.